# How to get XML into a Dictionary with an Expression?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, lambda

I have the following XML:

```
  <PerformancePanel page="PerformancePanel.ascx" title="">
    <FundGroup heading="Net Life Managed Funds">
      <fund id="17" countryid="N0" index="24103723" />
      <fund id="81" countryid="N0" index="24103723" /> 
      <fund id="127" countryid="N0" index="24103722" />
      <fund id="345" countryid="N0" index="24103723" />
      <fund id="346" countryid="N0" index="24103723" />
    </FundGroup>
    <FundGroup heading="Net Life Specialist Funds">
      <fund id="110" countryid="N0" index="24103717" />
      <fund id="150" countryid="N0" index="24103719" />
      <fund id="119" countryid="N0" index="24103720" />
      <fund id="115" countryid="N0" index="24103727" />
      <fund id="141" countryid="N0" index="24103711" />
      <fund id="137" countryid="N0" />
      <fund id="146" countryid="N0" />
      <fund id="133" countryid="N0" />
      <fund id="90" countryid="N0"  />
      <fund id="104" countryid="N0" />
      <fund id="96" countryid="N0" />
    </FundGroup>
  </PerformancePanel>
```

I can get the data into an anonymous object as follows:

```
    var offlineFactsheet = new
                               {
   PerformancePanels =
    (from panel in doc.Elements("PerformancePanel")
     select new PerformancePanel
     {
         PerformanceFunds = (from fg in panel.Elements("FundGroup")
                             select new
                             {
                                 Heading = (fg.Attribute("heading") == null)
                                            ? ""
                                            : (string)fg.Attribute("heading"),
                                 Funds =
                                    (from fund in fg.Elements("fund")
                                     select new Fund
                                     {
                                         FundId = (int)fund.Attribute("id"),
                                         CountryId = (string)fund.Attribute("countryid"),
                                         FundIndex = (fund.Attribute("index") == null)
                                                 ? null
                                                 : new Index
                                                 {
                                                     Id = (int)fund.Attribute("index")
                                                 },
                                         FundNameAppend = (fund.Attribute("append") == null)
                                                 ? ""
                                                 : (string)fund.Attribute("append")
                                     }).ToList()
                             }).ToDictionary(xx => xx.Heading, xx => xx.Funds)};
```

I'm trying to change my code such that I can assign the dictionary directly to a property of the class I'm working in, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015390/is-it-possible-to-load-a-usercontrol-into-an-anonymous-object-instead-of-just-in).
I'd like to have a Dictionary() where each header text is the key to the list of funds under it. I'm having difficulty applying the example in the linked question because that only returns a string, and this needs to return the dictionary.

This is the point that I got to before it occurred to me that I'm lost!!!:

```
this.PerformancePanels = doc.Elements("PerformancePanel").Select(e =>
 {
     var control = (PerformancePanel)LoadControl(this.OfflineFactsheetPath
                                                + (string)e.Attribute("page"));

     control.PerformanceFunds = e.Elements("FundGroup").Select(f =>
     {
         List<Fund> funds = (from fund in e.Elements("fund")
                             select new Fund
                                        {
                                            FundId = (int)fund.Attribute("id"),
                                            CountryId = (string)fund.Attribute("countryid"),
                                            FundIndex = (fund.Attribute("index") == null)
                                                            ? null
                                                            : new Index
                                                                  {
                                                                      Id = (int)fund.Attribute("index")
                                                                  },
                                            FundNameAppend = (fund.Attribute("append") == null)
                                                                 ? ""
                                                                 : (string)fund.Attribute("append")
                                        }).ToList();
         string heading = (e.Attribute("heading") == null)
                              ? ""
                              : (string)e.Attribute("heading");
     }).ToDictionary(xx => heading, xx => Funds);
     return control;
 }).ToList();
```

Could someone point me in the right direction please? I'm not even sure if 'Expression' is the right terminology. Could someone fill me in on that too? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
this.PerformancePanels = doc.Elements("PerformancePanel").Select(e =>
 {
     var control = (PerformancePanel)LoadControl(this.OfflineFactsheetPath
                                                + (string)e.Attribute("page"));



     control.PerformanceFunds = e.Elements("FundGroup").ToDictionary(xx => (string)xx.Attribute("heading"),
                                                                     xx => xx.Elements("fund").Select(g =>
          {
              Fund fund = new Fund
                              {
                                  FundId = (int)g.Attribute("id"),
                                  CountryId = (string)g.Attribute("countryid"),
                                  FundIndex = (g.Attribute("index") == null)
                                  ? null : new Index
                                               {
                                                   Id = (int)g.Attribute("index")
                                               },
                                  FundNameAppend = (g.Attribute("append") == null)
                                     ? ""
                                     : (string)g.Attribute("append")
                              };
              return fund;
          }).ToList());

     return control;
 }).ToList();
```

It turns out I didn't need to do the select(), just the ToDictionary() method, with the parameters being filled by the 'expressions'.. (if that's the right word?!)